# How to restructure equation so that the answer is a variable

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation to calculate the required power to heat a volume of water in an hour.

I want to restructure the equation so that I can find how many hours it would take to heat a volume of water at a particular power.

The equation I have is simple

```
Volume in litres * 4 * Temperature rise in celsius / 3412
```

An example would be

```
100 * 4 * 30 / 3412 = 3.516
```

This means that it would take 3.516 kW of power to heat 100 litres by 30 degrees in 1 hour.

Instead, I would like to use the volume in litres, temperature rise in celsius and required power to find how long it would take to heat to the target (in hours).

Thanks for your time, sorry to bother with such a simple question.

Comment: What is $4$ ? what is $3412$ ? Where is time in the equation ?

Comment: To be honest, I only know that they're constants. Since the time is 1 hour, I believe it's been excluded (since it would be multiplied by 1).

Comment: This is dubious. Why $4/3412$ instead of $1/853$ ?

Comment: [This is the page I got the calculation from if that helps](https://elementsofheating.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/how-to-calculate-the-kw-required-to-heat-a-volume-of-water-in-a-particular-time/). I'm not sure why it is like it is.

Comment: So you want to calculate the required TIME to heat up the volume? Then, I believe, this equation has little to do with the result. As you see, it doesn't say anything about time. More infomation about the process is required. Does the heating up involve phase changes? You need to calculate the required energy to make this heating up (with phase changes, if necessary) and divide the result by the power (which, I believe, is a constant). And then convert that result to hours.

Answer (score 1):

$$P=\frac{C\times V\times \Delta T} t$$ and

$$t=\frac{C\times V\times \Delta T} P.$$

You determine $C$ using the calculator with all ones.